# Both edges of Clk in VHDL Synthesis Coding

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, synthesis

Synthesis coding styles will implement in future ?
Or the IEEE-1076.6-200X standard allows simplify and enhance VHDL synthesis coding capability now ?

```
--Multiple Edge Registers
--Copyright © 2004 SynthWorks Design Inc. All Rights Reserved.
DualEdgeFF : process( nReset, Clk1, Clk2)
begin
  if (nReset = '0') then
    Q <= '0' ;
  elsif rising_edge(Clk1) then -- Functional Clock
    Q <= D ;
  elsif rising_edge(Clk2) then -- Scan Clock
    Q <= SD ;
  end if ;
  -- RTL_SYNTHESIS OFF
  if rising_edge(Clk1) and rising_edge(Clk2) then
    report "Warning: . . ." severity warning ;
    Q <= 'X' ;
  end if ;
-- RTL_SYNTHESIS ON
end process;

--Register Using Both Edges of Clk
DualEdge_Proc: process (Clk, Reset) is
begin
  if Reset = '1' then
    Q <= (others => '0');
  elsif rising_edge(Clk) then
    Q <= D4Rise;
  elsif falling_edge(Clk) then
    Q <= D4Fall;
  end if;
end process DualEdge_Proc;
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with VHDL standards, rather whether technology exists that has registers that use dual edges. AFAIK, there is no technology that currently uses both clock edges.

Comment: How do you think what did the author mean when publish the templates with Register Using Both Edges of Clk ?

Comment: Its a perfectly logical template that would map to a dual edge flip flop. But currently none exist.

Comment: At the time, I think there were ASIC libraries in which the BIST scan clock was separate from the functional clock.  Hence, this is the coding style the working group proposed to address that problem - of course if the technology does not implement it, it is reasonable to expect the code would not be synthesizable.   I no longer have the working group emails or data books, so it would be time consuming to research at this point.

Comment: OTOH, there is no excuse as to why the vendors have not implemented the DDR coding style.

Comment: @Tricky.  How about a dual-port RAM?   See below

Answer (score 0):

`if (nReset = '0') then
    Q <= '0' ;
    elsif rising_edge(Clk1) then -- Functional Clock
    Q <= D ;
    elsif rising_edge(Clk2) then -- Scan Clock
    Q <= SD ;
end if ;`

This can never map to anything sensible in the real-world. It is invalid design for synthesis.

`if Reset = '1' then
    Q <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(Clk) then
          Q <= D4Rise;
    elsif falling_edge(Clk) then
          Q <= D4Fall;
end if;`

This could map to a DDR IO output register.
FPGAs have this capability, but the tools are not capable of synthesizing this code today. They may support something like this in the future.
There are some issues as well, like D4Fall must reclocked from rising edge domain.

Currently you must instantiate technology specific DDR cells explicitly.

Comment: With the code that you mark "invalid design for synthesis" if you remove reset, it can be used for dual port RAM.

Comment: I guess some tool might possibly recognize that as dual port RAM... But the normal way to model dual port RAM is this:
if rising_edge(Clk1) then
   Q <= D;
end if;
if rising_edge(Clk2) then
   Q <= SD;
end if;

Comment: From a synthesis tool semantic, the only thing that changes is the order of implied priority.   WIth If then else, the first if branch has priority.   With if-end if, last assignment wins - hence, the 2nd if statement has precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The working group provided templates and rules for creating coding styles.   The examples above show some of the potential usage.   Granted, I have not recently seen the first coding style, although as I commented, I think at the time I was able to find such a register in an ASIC library that used it for Scan logic.

However, today, if we modify the shown code template slightly (but still compatible with 1076.6-2004), we have something that is useful.   Note I swapped the "elsif" for an "end if" and a separate "if" which is my preferred way to code this.

```
MemProc : process (ClkA, ClkB)
  type MemType is array (0 to 1023) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) ;
  variable Mem : MemType ;
begin
  if rising_edge(ClkA) then
    DataOutA <= Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrA))) ;
    if WriteA = '1' then
      Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrA))) := DataInA ;
    end if ;
  end if ;
  if rising_edge(ClkB) then
    DataOutB <= Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrB))) ;
    if WriteB = '1' then
      Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrB))) := DataInB ;
    end if ;
  end if ;
end process ;
```

You might also consider that the coding style that some FPGA vendors require is not language legal.   The type of a shared variable must be a protected type.  Shared variables with ordinary types was temporarily legal in VHDL-93, but as noted in VHDL-93 this was fixed in the next revision which is VHDL-2000/2002.

If FPGA vendors want to do something efficient and language legal, they can replace their illegal code with OSVVM MemoryPkg code to implement the memory models as a proper protected type.   The reason I say this is efficient is because MemoryPkg implements a data structure that only implements memory as it is used.   You can find OSVVM at github and osvvm.org.

```
library OSVVM;
use OSVVM.MemoryPkg.all;

architecture ...
  shared variable ptRam : MemoryPType ;
begin
  ptRam.MemInit(
AddrWidth => Address'length, DataWidth => Data'length
) ;

MemAProc : process (ClkA)
begin
  if rising_edge(ClkA) then
    DataOutA <= ptRam.MemRead(AddrA) ; ;
    if WriteA = '1' then
      ptRam.MemWrite(AddrA, DataInA) ;
    end if ;
  end if ;
end process ;

MemBProc : process (ClkB)
begin
  if rising_edge(ClkB) then
    DataOutB <= ptRam.MemRead(AddrB) ; ;
    if WriteB = '1' then
      ptRam.MemWrite(AddrB, DataInB) ;
    end if ;
  end if ;
end process ;
```

You might be saying, no it is too hard to synthesize a protected type.   The simple answer is, you don't have to.   You can not synthesize most of the code in either std_logic_1164 or numeric_std either - don't believe me, try taking the code from rising_edge and using all of that in an if statement to make a flip-flop.

Comment: Afaik, vendors accept signal instead of shared variable for RAM inference. The shared variable is only useful for inferring write before read RAM. Altera have always used signal in their example (Xilinx use shared variable). The problem is it is legal with '93 VHDL. 
It is also default behaviour with some simulators (afaik) that lack of protected type is only a warning to ensure proper backwards compatability by default. Strict mode is required to enforce an error.

Comment: I have had some luck with signals - it may have been Altera, I can't remember.   That does require the one process form though.   If you are using signals with multiple processes, then it is not true dual port (ie: write and read from either port).